# aws sts AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityInput

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-iam, sts-securitytokenservice

I'm having problems using the AWS STS service to give temporary user access to the console. I can use the IDP and AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityInput method to retrieve credentials fine and have tested the credentials as working using the aws-cli tools, but providing a redirect into the console simply, despite numerous attempts/permutations doesn't work. I simple get the message: ***"Some of your credentials are missing. Please contact your administrator."***
Note: the attached policy to the role whom has the trust with custom IDP is AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess. Note: I also tried the GetFederatedToken(), which ends the same way; the credentials work for the API, but try the sign-in and redirect I can't access the console. Has anyone come across this? ... this there something i'm missing in the policy to permit console access?

I also tried added the policy document to the request, again, nothing more an then copy and paste of the AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess policy, but no dice

```
// assume the identity - works fine - i recieve my credentials
// and i can use the access_id, secret and session token placed  
// a /.aws/credentials fine

input := &sts.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityInput{
            RoleArn:         aws.String("arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/USER-web-identity"),
            RoleSessionName:  aws.String(context.email),
            WebIdentityToken: aws.String(context.token.Encode()),
            DurationSeconds:  aws.Int64(900),
        }

.. skipping code

// a then try and give the user access to the console as
// described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html
params := &url.Values{}
params.Add("Action", "getSigninToken")
params.Add("SessionType", "json")
params.Add("Session", string(encoded))


// I receive the signintoken response fine and encode into a
// redirect url to the console
query := &url.Values{}
query.Add("Action", "login")
query.Add("Issuer", "https://127.0.0.1:3000/sso/session")
query.Add("Destination", "https://console.aws.amazon.com")
query.Add("SigninToken", token)

cx.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, fmt.Sprintf("%s?%s", signInURL, query.Encode()))

// get nothing but "Some of you credentials are missing"
```